# Time zone for Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP

Tags: timezone, firebase

It appears that when I use `Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` currently, it is using PDT (I assume that will be changing to PST in the fall).

Is there a way to get this in UTC instead of PDT?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Firebase timestamps are always stored as milliseconds since the [epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) (midnight of 1/1/1970 in UTC). This is the same way that dates work in Javascript and many other languages. This is a timezone-agnostic way of representing time.

Generally speaking, timezone only plays a role in how a time is displayed to a user, not in how it's represented under-the-hood. Firebase timestamps are no different.

So, if you construct a JS date object using a timestamp created by Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP, it will automatically have the same timezone as the machine on which it is being displayed.

Comment: You're exactly right ... for some reason I confused myself. Thanks!