# FirebaseServerValue.timestamp() gives future time

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I'm using observeEventType .ChildAdded to load all messages which include all timestamps from Firebase server. The problem is that Firebase always fires a placeholder timestamp (aka, local time) first, then replace it with a second call back which has the correct timestamp from the server. This behavior requires to load the message page twice to get correct timestamps, because the first time it only shows local time. Well, I have figured out a way to only display the correct timestamp. By using .ChildChanged, I can ignore the first timestamp and just retrieve the second one. However, this call back gives me future time, exactly one hour two minutes ahead, and I have no clue how to solve this. I have googled for days, but no luck. please help me out here. The following is my code:

To save timestamp:

```
let timestamp = FirebaseServerValue.timestamp() let newData = ["sender":     "John", "timestamp": timestamp]
ref.childByAppendingPath("messages").childByAppendingPath(ref.authData.uid).setValue(newData)
```

In my message VC, to retrieve timestamp:

```
    handle = ref.observeEventType(.ChildChanged, withBlock: { (snapshot) in

    let text = snapshot.value["message"] as! String

    let sender = snapshot.value["sender"] as! String

    let timestamp = snapshot.value["timestamp"] as! NSTimeInterval

    let date = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: timestamp/1000)

    // TESTING DATE
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()

    dateFormatter.AMSymbol = "AM"

    dateFormatter.PMSymbol = "PM"

    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm, MM'/'dd'/'YY"

    let dateString = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date)

    print(dateString)
```

And the output is

```
03:37, 02/14/16
```

but current time is:

```
02:35, 02/14/16
```

Comment: I just ran the code (well, minus the `sender`, since you don't set a value for that) and it printed `5:55` (which is the local time). So it works for me. You might want to first simply print the `timestamp` that you get from Firebase. If that value is correct, the problem is in the conversion code.

Comment: so I saved with .timestamp() and tested it with .ChildChanged just now. the time is like 5 hours ahead of me. I'm in PA, USA, it was 7:00 pm 2/14 but the output was 00:03 2/15. Here is my code:        ref.childByAppendingPath("messages").childByAppendingPath("-KAUbSmAvUpqw2usUQAk").childByAppendingPath("-KAXEBrLRwu8Z15BLdk0").observeEventType(.ChildChanged, withBlock: { snapshot in
            
            let timestamp = snapshot.value as! NSTimeInterval
            
            let date = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: timestamp/1000)
            
            print(date)
        
        })

Comment: What did I miss? Can you show me how you get the output?

Comment: Wait a second, I think that's UTC time, but why didn't the server give me my local time?

Comment: Even when I tried to convert it to local time with NSTimeZone.localTimeZone(), it still gives me an hour and two minutes ahead of my local time

Comment: On your question about timezones: Firebase stores timestamps in epoch format (milliseconds since 1/1/1970 in UTC) See  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17637408/time-zone-for-firebase-servervalue-timestamp. Since it's based on UTC, converting to local timezone should be done in your code.

Comment: I used your code: `print(timestamp)` shows `1455517363315.0` and then 
`print(dateString)` shows `07:22, 02/15/16` (which is correct, since I'm in CET at the moment). Print the timestamp you get back and check if it's equally correct with a tool like http://www.epochconverter.com/.

Comment: Yes, I just tried to print out the timestamp value and literally copied and pasted the raw value to epochconverter.com and the time is one hour ahead of my local time... I'm very confused... could it be my computer time is wrong?

Comment: ok... I just made the most ridiculous mistake in my whole life... It turns out that my computer time was off and I didn't realize that