# Firebase Time Stamp Value And Query | JavaScript

Tags: javascript, android, ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I wan't to save some data in Firebase using mobile app (iOS & Android) and to fetch this data via web application with different queries, each data node consists of date, userid, etc.

Update : i used below JavaScript code to fetch data from Firebase that posted today only (set date Hours to morning so its keep get the data for the all day long and not to be changed with each page refresh or reopen)

```
var currentdate = new Date();
currentdate.setHours(0,0,0,0);
ref.orderByChild("orderDate").startAt(currentdate.getTime()).on('child_added', function (snapshot) {
 var test = snapshot.child("orderTotal").val();
window.alert(test);
});
```

The currentdate.getTime() value is : **1492462800000 = Mon, 17 Apr 2017 21:00:00 GMT** which is yesterday **@ 09:00 PM** and not midnight **12:00 AM** ?
And i have also post some data to Firebase today **Tue, 18 Apr 2017** and according to my query startAt(currentdate.getTime()) its should return todays post but its just return nothing ? 
I have replaced the currentdate.getTime() with 1 of my posts dates and its works fine **1492524624** .

please could some one show me what is wrong here ?

Comment: have a look on this converter. -> https://currentmillis.com

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17637408/time-zone-for-firebase-servervalue-timestamp. Essentially the two services and the device you used all seem to use a different timezone for converting the timestamp to a display date. Since there is a single value stored in Firebase (milliseconds since midnight of 1/1/1970 in UTC), there is nothing that Firebase can do about that.

Answer (score 1):

That seems like a time-zone difference. [Check this answer out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17643005/7865277)

You're basically storing everything in one time-zone format and then convert for each client.

Comment: so according to this question you post this should not effect my queries , right ?